# mysql SELECT with condition preference

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

i have a database with 4 fields, i want to search user from that database by multiple or conditions, the problem is how to index the selection according to number of true or conditions.
fields are course, school, college, city
i want that the results should be displayed according to number of true or conditions here is the code

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("xxx.xx.xxx.xxx","myusername","mypassword");
    if (!$con)
      {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    mysql_select_db("character", $con);
    $searchfrnd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (course='physics' or  school='st thomas' or college='mit' or city='austin'))");
    WHILE($display = mysql_fetch_array($searchfrnd))
    {
    $frnd=$display[userid];
    echo $frnd;
    }
    ?>
```

- i just want the the precedence of the result displayed should be in decreasing order of number of true OR conditions.In other words in decsending order of number of matching values

Comment: I'm sorry but I really didn't get what you're asking. Could you explain with some example?

Comment: for example if in the last row of the table all parameters are matching it should be displayed first, what happens now is the result displayed is not according to number of true OR conditions its according to the way it is arranged in table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM user 
WHERE surname='jack' 
  OR  school='st' 
  OR college='austin' 
  OR city='mit'
ORDER BY (
  IF(surname='jack', 1, 0)
  + IF(school='st', 1, 0)
  + IF(college='austin' , 1, 0)
  + IF(city='mit', 1, 0)
) DESC;
```

Answer (score 3):

you could do something like this

```
select (case when surname = 'jack' then 1 else 0 end +
        case when school ='st' then 1 else 0 end +
        case when college='mit' then 1 else 0 end +
        case when city='austin' then 1 else 0 end) as score,
        *
from 
user 
WHERE surname='jack' or  
      school='st'     or 
      college='mit' or 
      city='austin')
order by score desc;
```

Comment: this one worked! also i will like to inform that the bobs method is also good

Comment: Best answer for the question. Height of conceptualization.