# MySQL selecting missing rows

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with user info:

```
    user_id | meta_key | meta_value
 -----------+----------+-------------
      1     | name     | John
      1     | surname  | Doe
      2     | name     | Luke
      3     | name     | Jane
```

I want to select rows with a certain key, given a list of IDs.

If I do:

```
SELECT meta_value FROM table WHERE meta_key = 'surname' AND user_id IN(1,2,3)
```

MySQL will only return the info for user 1, since the others do not have surname.

I would like to build a query to return exactly the number of rows as the IDs passed, with NULL (or an empty string) if that particular user has no surname in the table.

I have tried to use `IFNULL(meta_value, "")` and also using `IF`, but it does not seem to help.

Any suggestions? I am sure it's a trivial thing but I can't seem to get around this issue.

Here's a SQLfiddle showing the issue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86eef2/6

My expected output would be:

```
Doe
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: Try meta_value IS NOT NULL.

Comment: @nico Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335787/mysql-select-with-condition-preference any help?

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla but I want the rows where meta_value is NULL, that would exclude them, won't it?

Comment: @rlb.usa sort of... trying to use `CASE` but I must be missing something...

Comment: @nico I feel like you could get better faster help if you used something like sqlfiddle

Comment: @rlb.usa there you go ! :)

Comment: @nico how about a `CASE` statement like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86eef2/10 Notice that the `WHERE meta_key` has moved to the `CASE` now. I feel certain there are shorter statements that can be used but for learning purposes I like to demonstrate `CASE` especially since this is only a snippet of what you are actually doing and will likely need to be expanded.

Comment: @rlb.usa the problem is each user_id will have several entries and I only need to get one per each ID, so in this case I want 3 rows while your query returns 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id,
(SELECT meta_value FROM mytable B WHERE B.user_id = mytable.user_id AND META_KEY = 'surname') AS 'surname_meta_value'
FROM mytable
WHERE user_id IN(1,2,3)
```

For study purpose, this could be a faster option, in most cases, based on **rlb.usa** solution:

```
SELECT user_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(
(CASE WHEN meta_key = "surname" 
    THEN meta_value
    ELSE '' 
END) SEPARATOR '')
AS 'surname_meta_value'
FROM mytable WHERE user_id IN(1,2,3)
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: This is another possibility but it has a `O(n^2)` runtime which might be expensive - or not! Really depends on how much data OP has and how fast it needs to be.

Comment: I'm going to try this on my real data and let you know

Comment: @rlb.usa, I am not sure, if this second option is faster with more data, can you please check this.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Yes it is going to be faster, it is an `O(n)` runtime as it does not need a new query for each row. : )

Comment: The second option is indeed 30+ times faster on my real DB!